# Blending when strokes crosses each other in Metal

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I draw small squares which is overlapping in fixed interval so that it feels like texture brush in Drawing Application.

Currently I use the Pipeline Descriptor

```
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .one
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

My aim is when the two strokes crosses each other i want to have a white color like Blend mode additive in OpenGL

I attached a photo what i currently getting.

[image]

when the stokes crosses it should appear in white.

Suggest a way to achieve

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not set the blendingEnabled property on the MTLRenderPipelineColorAttachmentDescriptor. Also, make sure you are using sRGB textures so that the sampler will know how to decode 8 bit values to linear light while blending.